# Merging query from same table into different columns

Tags: sql, group-by, pivot

I'm having an issue querying a table for some information. Basically the way data was stored in the table, for every customer, its information was stored vertically and so on for others.

In my case I want to display in separate columns for example only the `'Company'`  and `'StreetAddress'` values from all their information for each `CustomerId`.

I tried joins, unions and pivots but my skills with sql are still limited. This is how the original table looks like:

[image]

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pivot with conditional aggregation. If you want three columns in the resultset that contain the id of the customer, their company and street address, you can do:

```
select
    customerid,
    max(case when key = 'Company' then value end) company,
    max(case when key = 'StreetAddress' then value end) street_address
from mytable
group by customerid
```